# using undefined Variable in php function

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and working on script that may have undefined variable and I have two ways to handle this, my question is what is the best way.

Variable `$_GET['page']` can be sometimes defined and sometimes undefined.

the first way I check with isset() and if:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $sql.=limitrows($_GET['page'],10);
}else{
    $sql.=limitrows(1,10);
}
```

the second way I just write the function and using `@` remove the error and handle the `isset()` inside the function

```
 function limitrows($page=1, $rows=10){
       if (isset($page)==false or $page<=0 ){
         $page=1;
       }
  }

 $sql.=@limitrows($_GET['page'],10);
```

the second way make my code much cleaner and I do all the dirty work inside the function but it show error and I have to `@`. 
What is the best way?

Comment: Keep always the code in control then use isset and dontt mask error ,... (never...) but eventually manage  the error with try catch

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: chris85 this is not full function I just put only what I asked and this is how should I use '@' but if needed I can write what it return.

Comment: the code work fine the only problem is that how to handle  when I have undefined variable. :)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a [filter function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to access the GET parameter.

```
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

With this approach, `$page` will *always* be set, so you won't need to worry about undefined index warnings. (If `'page'` is not a key in `$_GET`, `filter_input` will return `null`.)

Then, when you need to use `$page` later, checking it is simpler:

```
function limitrows($page, $rows=10) {
    if (!$page) $page = 1;   // assuming you don't have a page 0, or
    // if ($page === null) $page = 1; // if you DO have a page 0
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `array_key_exists` to check for the existence of an array key. You can use an `if` statement, or shorten it with a ternary.

```
// with if
$page = 1;
if (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) === true) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// with ternary
$page = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) === true ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Do not use the `@` error suppression operator. It is a bad practice to get into, 99.99% of the time you want to see all errors in all situations.

The "best way" in coding is a combination of opinion, established code style, and industry best practices. Generally speaking, one should use the right functions for the job (in this case, `array_key_exists` or `filter_input` as indicated in another answer), not use error handling, suppression, or exceptions for normal code flow, and be explicit/verbose rather than trying for the shortest code. You might be able to condense something into 1 line rather than 3, but to what end? All it does is increase the specific complexity of any given part of your code, making it harder for others (and yourself!) to understand and maintain in the future.

In terms of where to do what, gather your arguments outside the function AND validate the arguments inside the function.

**Documentation/More Reading**

- `array_key_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- Ternary operator - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- PHP The Right way, *see: "Inline Error Suppression"* - 
  http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: "gather your arguments outside the function AND validate the arguments inside the function" I strongly agree. No need to limit the usability of your function by tying it to `$_GET` or some other specific source.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator

```
$sql.=@limitrows(isset($_GET['page'])?$_Get['page']:1,10);
```

format [logic]?[true]:[false]

Comment: I like this way, but you too, using @ and without it, it return error.